# how to unexposed asp.net code web.config?

Tags: asp.net, encryption, webforms

I wrote a simple application code in ASP.NET Web Forms  and I want to publish the code  on the site of Microsoft, but the file containing the password and user ID  to the database web host in the web.config connection string  i don't want to expose , How can I do this?

Comment: mask the user name and password. People re-using your code will change them to their own credentials anyway.

Comment: _Password_ and _UserId_ of a db connection? MVC, WebForms, ASP.NET Version?

Comment: WebForms ,connection string

Comment: i need the web.config to access to the web host that containing my app database but i don't want to expose the code

Answer (score 0):

You can actually encrypt sections of the web.config file, depending on the version of .Net you're using.

Take a look at these articles, [Old Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky(v=vs.100).aspx) with ASP.NET and [Latest version](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure). Also, another thing to consider is that the server would need to be 'hacked', end users cannot browse to `web.config`.